# flexsearch query with multiple words in multiple fields

Tags: javascript, flexsearch

I use [flexsearch](https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch) javascript library to index a set of objects and make queries on it.

Consider this index definition:

```
const databaseIndex = new Document({
    preset: 'match',
    tokenize: 'full',
    language: 'it',
    resolution: 1,
    charset: 'latin:advanced',
    document: {
        id: 'id',
        index: ['id', 'brand', 'name'],
    },
});
```

I add the items to the document like this:

```
rawProductsList.forEach((element) => {
    databaseIndex.add(element);
});
```

Consider a simple set of objects like this:

```
id  brand   name    
------------------- 
0   oreo    biscuit     
1   barilla biscuit
```

When I search for `oreo` or `biscuit` I get the correct results, but what I want to achieve is that a query `oreo biscuit` gives me the object with id 1, but in my configuration it doesn't return anything.

How can I do it?

Comment: I never used the Document object, but using Index you can try this: https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch#append-contents